# Owl-Carousel Free Slide Move

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to put the Owl-Carousel to work with free items pushing, with total controller of the user, but the items is moving to the border when the user slide it..

Example:

```
Item 1 - Item 2 - Item 3 - Item 4(only half is showing)...
```

So i want to push only a little, and it's happening:

```
Item 2 - Item 3 - Item 5(only half is showing)...
```

I want to total control of carousel, to if i push just a little, show like this:

```
Item 1(only half) - item 2 - item 3 - item 4
```

I tried to clear my question most possible, i just want to the items don't go to the border even if the user push just a little of the carousel..

My config is that:

```
      <script>
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                margin:12,
                checkVisible: false,
                loop: true,
                responsive:{
                    0:{                     
                        items:3,
                        margin:4,
                        autoWidth:false,
                    },
                    426:{
                        items:3,
                        margin:8,
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:2,
                        margin:8,
                    },
                    700:{
                        items:4,
                        margin:12,
                        autoWidth:true,
                    },
                }
            });
        </script>
```

**I tried** freeDrag and pullDrag options but doesn't work as expected..